# Search Python Dictionary and increment value where found

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a data dictionary in python:

```
    [
    {u'PhoneOwner': u'Bob', u'Frequency': 0, u'PhoneNumber': u'123456789'},
    {u'PhoneOwner': u'Sarah', u'Frequency': 0, u'PhoneNumber': u'98765431'}
    ]
```

I have a list of calls made using PhoneNumber, I want to try and compare the list to the dictionary and update the frequency when a number from my list is in the dictionary, eventually getting to:

```
    [
    {u'PhoneOwner': u'Bob', u'Frequency': 5, u'PhoneNumber': u'123456789'},
    {u'PhoneOwner': u'Sarah', u'Frequency': 8, u'PhoneNumber': u'98765431'}
    ]
```

At the moment I have:

```
      with open("CallLog.txt") as connectedNumbers:         
      for line in connectedNumbers:
      try:
              phoneNumberDictionary[PhoneNumber] += phoneNumberDictionary[Frequency]1
      except KeyError:
              phoneNumberDictionary[PhoneNumber] = phoneNumberDictionary[Frequency]1
```

I can't find any details on how to search one field of the dictionary and update another if a match is found. 
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your input is not a dictionary, but a list of dictionaries.

Comment: The thing is, you don't have a dictionary; you have a list of dicts. There's no way of indexing phoneNumberDictionary by phone number, without iterating all the way through each time to find the right dict.

Comment: If you want a dictionary indexed on phone numbers, you need: `{123456789: (u'Bob', 0), ...}` or `{123456789: {'Owner': 'Bob', 'Frequency': 0}, ...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot search the values of the dictionary: it is indexed by its keys, and values are not indexed at all (in fact, they might not even be hashable).

You then have two options:

1. Reformulate your problem so that the phone number is actually the key:

   ```
   {
        u'123456789': {u'PhoneOwner': u'Bob', u'Frequency': 0},
        u'98765431': {u'PhoneOwner': u'Sarah', u'Frequency': 0},
   }
   ```

   This is quite practical in that it lets you index your dictionary immediately:

   ```
   with open("Calllog.txt") as log:
       for line in log:
           phoneNumberDictionary[line]['Frequency'] += 1
   ```

   But it means you'll have to rework your data, possibly heavily, and this might not be the most convenient with whatever else you want to do with your data (e.g. search by owner name)
2. Keep your data structure as a list, and search the matches directly through it:

   ```
   with open("Calllog.txt") as log:
       for line in log:
           entries = filter(lambda entry: entry['PhoneNumber'] == line, phoneNumberDirectory)
           for entry in entries:
               entry['Frequency'] += 1
   ```

   That will work beautifully (and let have several people have the same phone number. Good, bad ? that's up to you to decide), but it's obviously quite innefficient as you walk your entire directory every time. This might be the best solution if you have a known little dataset though.
3. (In my opinion, the best option) some combination of the two. You can typically store your data in an object, with multiple indices as dictionaries:

   ```
   class PhoneNumbers(object):
       def __init__(self, entries):
           self.frequencies = []
           self.names = {}
           self.numbers = {}
           for i, entry in enumerate(entries):
               self.frequencies.append(entry['Frequency'])
               self.names[entry['PhoneOwner']] = entry['PhoneNumber']
               self.numbers[entry['PhoneNumber']] = i

       def register_call(self, number):
           self.frequencies[self.numbers[number]] += 1

   data = PhoneNumbers(phoneNumberDictionary)
   with open("Calllog.txt") as log:
       for line in log:
           data.register_call(line)
   ```

   Or some variation around these lines which matches what you intend to do with your data.

Comment: So I've been able to reformat the data, but trying to increment the frequency throws up error: phoneNumberDictionary[18667209918]['Frequency'] += 1
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: It's hard to say where this comes from without seeing your data exacly, but it seems like `phoneNumberDictionary[18667209918]` is a string; have you made sure you have correctly initialised your dictionary entries with dictionaries ?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, my syntax wasn't correct which was causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a suggestion:

Turn phoneNumberDict into a dictionary-of-dictionaries. Each key will be a phone number, each value will be a `dict` with the rest of the information. In this way, you won't need to loop over the list of dictionaries each time.

Observe:

```
phoneNumberDictionary = { 
                         '123456789': {u'PhoneOwner': u'Bob', u'Frequency': 0},
                         '987654321': {u'PhoneOwner': u'Sarah', u'Frequency': 0}
                        }
callLogList = ['123456789', 
               '123456789', 
               '123456789', 
               '123456789', 
               '123456789', 
               '987654321', 
               '987654321', 
               '987654321', 
               '987654321', 
               '987654321', 
               '987654321', 
               '987654321', 
               '987654321',
               '000000000'
              ]

for phoneNumber in callLogList:
    if phoneNumber in phoneNumberDictionary:
        phoneNumberDictionary[phoneNumber]['Frequency'] += 1

print (phoneNumberDictionary)
```

Without needing to loop through a list of phone numbers every time, this will be a much more efficient script, especially as the list of phone numbers grows.

I've also changed the for loop's `try-except` to an if statement as this will be faster than catching an exception every time a number is not included. I've included a dud phone number so you can see that it still works correctly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What a fantastic answer, thank you.
I never thought to put the data into a dict of dict's. That makes so much sense.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't too late to change your data structure, it would be much more efficient to change from a list of dicts to a dict of dicts with the top-level dict using the phone number as the key. If you were using a list because order is important, you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes).

To answer your question using your current data structure: since you have a list of dictionaries, the first thing you need to do is find the dictionary that corresponds to the phone number that you want to increment. You could use a function like `index_dict_in_list()` below to do this:

```
def index_dict_in_list(list_, key, value):
    """
    Given a list of dicts, a key, and a value, return the
    index of the dict with the matching key:value pair.
    """
    for idx, dict_ in enumerate(list_):
        if dict_[key] == value:
            return idx
    return -1
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
phonebook = [
    {u'PhoneOwner': u'Bob', u'Frequency': 0, u'PhoneNumber': u'123456789'},
    {u'PhoneOwner': u'Sarah', u'Frequency': 0, u'PhoneNumber': u'98765431'}
]

page = index_dict_in_list(phonebook, 'PhoneNumber', '98765431')
phonebook[page]['Frequency'] =+ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, you have a list of dictionary, you have to iterate through the list and check if the line matches with `PhoneNumber` of that particular dictionary. If matches, increment `Frequency` of the dictionary by 1.

```
  with open("CallLog.txt") as connectedNumbers:         
  for line in connectedNumbers:
      for value in data:
          if line== value['PhoneNumber']:
              value['Frequency']+=1
```